# Using RegEX To Prefix And Append In Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex, find-and-replace, prefix

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283608/using-regex-to-prefix-and-append-in-notepad) on StackOverflow. It worked great but I also need to include lines that have non-alphabet characters in it like:

```
some_name
some.name
```

And add prefixes like this:

```
start:"some_name"  
start:"some.name"
```

Based on the the other topic I'm guessing I need a regex that matches dots and such besides just regular text.

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind. Found the answer:

```
^(.*)$
```